# Derivation step in paper on LDA

Tags: derivatives, optimization, partial-derivative, digamma-function

I am wondering how do the authors of this [paper](https://www.jmlr.org/papers/volume3/blei03a/blei03a.pdf) perform the following step (in the paper it is on page 29):

$$\dfrac{\partial L}{\partial \gamma_i}=\Psi^\prime(\gamma_i)\left(\alpha_i + \sum_{n=1}^N\phi_{ni}-\gamma_i\right)-\Psi^\prime\left(\sum_{j=1}^k\gamma_j\right)\sum_{j=1}^k\left(\alpha_j+\sum_{n=1}^N\phi_{nj}-\gamma_j\right)=0$$

Maximized for:

$$\gamma_i=\alpha_i+\sum_{n=1}^N\phi_{ni}$$

Does anyone know the calculations for this step?
($\Psi'$ is the derivative of the digamma function, everything else is a variable)

Comment: I think they just mean that if you plug in $\gamma_i = \alpha_i + \sum_n \phi_{ni}$ into the expressions for the partial derivatives, you get zero.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just plugging the $\gamma_i$ and $\gamma_j$ into the second and fourth brackets turns those brackets into 0. And thus the expression into 0.